# Why does my electricity blow when I plug in my oven?

Tags: electrical, oven

I have a Sauter (electric) oven that was working fine last week. It was unplugged for a few days. Now, when I try to plug it in, it blows the main electric fuse. This happens with all the dials turned off. I tried plugging it into another outlet, but it also blows the fuse, so the problem is clearly with the oven (other appliances are working fine in the kitchen).

What can this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a short somewhere in the oven where hot is making contact with neutral or ground (the frame).  This could be anywhere but the easiest thing to do is start at the plug and work your way up. Check the plug and cable for any signs of damage.  If the damage is at the plug or cable then it is something you can fix pretty easily - replacement parts are easy to come by at your local hardware store.

If a quick visual inspection does not show anything you will need to start disassembling the oven and tracing the electrical connections, looking for anything damaged like nicked conductors, missing insulators, etc.  If you do not have experience working on electrical components it is best to contact a qualified service technician for your appliance.

Do not use the oven until this is resolved. Do not short out the fuse or try a larger fuse.

Answer (score 3):

Your appliance has developed a dangerous internal defect, and must be repaired or replaced.